# Does Android's Intent use Googles cloud at all?

Tags: android

Sorry I'm new to Android handsets.  When you do a startActivity(intent) does it involve hitting Googles cloud services at all to resolve the [handler] or is this purely a local call?

Answer (score 4):

Intents are handled locally. Which is good because you can open applications without an internet connection.